# Connection to multiple db with spring mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a many users on my site. each user has his own database. When user send request I want to perform it from user's db in mongodb database. How I can make this with spring.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you want, what have you achieved so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: I made sure that all requests work with the same database. All users. How to set up the spring so that the database is taken from the request and the controller has already worked with the base of the particular user.

Comment: Your question needs to be edited for everyone willing to help understand it better. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).